# Retain partitions while streaming and upserting to delta table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

I am currently streaming using writestream to write to an existing delta table in order to add an additional attribute.

I am using the foreachBatch function which contains a user defined function to upsert based on a match/no match situation between the delta table and the incoming micro batch:

```
# function to carry out upsert operations in the foreachbatch function in the writestream
def upsert_function(microdf, batchid):

  # deduplicate the specific microbatch
  microdf = microdf.dropDuplicates(['year', 'month', 'day', 'attribute_value', 'platform', 'user_id', 'attribute_count'])

  (delta_df.alias('target')
   .merge(
     microdf.alias('update'),
     condition = 'target.year = update.year AND target.month = update.month AND target.day = update.day AND target.attribute_value = update.attribute_value AND target.platform = update.platform AND target.user_id = update.user_id'
   )
   # app_bundle_id_count is updated in the delta table if the value in the microbatch is greater than the one in the delta table at that instance
   .whenMatchedUpdate(
     set = {'attribute_count':(F.when(F.col('target.attribute_count') < F.col("update.attribute_count"), F.col("update.attribute_count"))
                                   .otherwise(F.col('target.attribute_count')))}
   )
   # for no match, insert all columns into delta table
   .whenNotMatchedInsertAll()
   .execute()
  )
```

The upsert works as I want it to but the issue is that the existing partition structure in the S3 bucket which is year -> month -> day and when I run the upsert function the paritioning is ignored and the files just get stored without partitioning in the destination folder.

```
writing_stream = (
      df.writeStream
        .option("mergeSchema", "true")
        .trigger(availableNow=True)
        .outputMode('update')
        .option('checkpointLocation', check_point_path)
        .queryName(stream_name)
        .foreachBatch(upsert_to_delta)
        .start()
        .write.option("mergeSchema", "true").format('delta').mode('append')
        .partitionBy('year', 'month', 'day')
        .save(location)
        )
```

What am I missing here? Any input would be appreciated greatly. Thanks very much :)

The upsert works as I want it to but the issue is that the existing partition structure in the S3 bucket which is year -> month -> day and when I run the upsert function the paritioning is ignored and the files just get stored without partitioning in the destination folder.

I tried also to add the partition logic within the upsert function but it is also ignored.

Is it better to complete the upsert on the delta table and then write it to the s3 bucket such as:

```
writing_stream.awaitTermination()

(delta_df.write
  .partitionBy('year', 'month', 'day')
  .option("mergeSchema", "true")
  .mode('append')
  .format('delta')
  .save(location)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solved! Seems like the issue was that when I had shallow cloned the table for testing, I had enabled Delta Lake column mapping. By doing this, I also enabled random file prefixes, which removes the ability to explore data using Hive-style partitioning.

Please see this described here: https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta/delta-column-mapping.html#drop-columns